# PHP variable name syntax: numbers and variables as part of a variable name

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a variable defined as an array, which is built in a loop:

```
$years=array("2010","2011","2012");

    foreach($years as $year)
    {
    ///an SQL query + some PDO that queries a different table based on $year
    $dataset_full_{$year} = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

so you end up with a set of arrays named

```
$dataset_full_2010
$dataset_full_2011
$dataset_full_2012
```

when I `print_r($dataset_full_2012);` however I get nothing, but if I go ahead and define

```
$current_year="2012";
```

then

```
print_r($dataset_full_{$current_year});
```

I get my array. What piece of syntax am I misusing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe, you can always use an intermediate string:

```
$var_name = "dataset_full_" . $year;
$$var_name = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can also use concatenation within curly braces:

```
${"dataset_full_" . $year} = ...
```

[Here's the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)